# AWS Elastic Beanstalk 500 Internal Server Error with Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed a django server using AWS Elastic Beanstalk a week ago.

There were no issues after I deployed the server and it worked without problems.

However, I accessed today the server, there are Internal Server Error.

I did not deploy any edited things on the server but it shows 500 errors.

I have no ideas about this issue. Does anyone give advice on this?

[image]

Comment: what does the logs say, it looks like an apache error to me

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the 500 error in my eb server.

There are two issues in my error.

First, requirements.txt folder's location.

beanstalk read the location and recognizes modules automatically in requirements.txt.

requirements.txt must be in the same location of .elasticbeanstalk folder.

In my case, requirements.txt file was in the upper directory.

I can see the error log in cloud watch. cloud watch is very very useful tool for error tracking.

I checked this problem for two days.